# Undo region spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, region, undo

I really appreciate the undo in region command in standard emacs, where you can just mark a region and only changes made in that region are undone.

This doesn't seem to work in the default spacemacs configuration.

Is there a way to activate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the region and do, either:
`SPC SPC undo`
or
`C-_` that is `Control-shift-`-`key`

or even better, you can create your own keymap under `SPC o` that's reserved for user keybindings, and create `SPC o u` for `undo`:

```
(spacemacs/declare-prefix "o" "personal")

;; File bindings
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys
  "ou" 'undo)
```

Comment: Thanks. The `C-_` command works, but the marked region extends after the first time I press it (weird, but not the end of the world). `SPC SPC undo` doesn't do this, oddly enough.

Comment: Also, it seems like a shorter undo history is kept then before. If I edit a region, then do an undo and redo somewhere else, the undo-history for the original region seems to be lost.

Comment: Actually,  I can't reliably reproduce it now. Never mind. I'll post a new question if I manage to.

Answer (score 3):

`(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "u") 'undo)`

It will bind <kbd>u</kbd> to Emacs undo command in evil visual state (aka when you select region).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, would you mind adding some explanation to increase its usefullness?

Answer (score 1):

As of July 15, 2022, there exists a flag to enable `undo-region` with vim style key bindings in the Spacemacs develop -- which also happens to currently be the default, rolling release -- branch. Users can edit the `.spacemacs` file to include the following,

```lisp
 (setq-default dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
                '((spacemacs-editing :variables
                                     vim-style-enable-undo-region t)))
```

For the related git pull request, see https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/pull/15631

Comment: What does *"5 years later"* mean? Could you please provide some info that identifies the particular *version* of Spacemacs (or whatever)  that provides this? Presumably the link you show provides that info somewhere, but it really belongs in the answer text as well, to be most helpful. Thx.

Comment: I hate link rot as much as the next guy, answer updated. Appreciate the moderation towards high quality content.