# Undo one specific line in a text file within Emacs

Tags: undo, lines, mouse-pointer

Usually when doing the normal undo it will undo all code changes since you went into insert-mode (for me it's evil-undo).
I was wondering if it were possible to implement a function that will only undo the line your cursor is currently hovering over in elisp, if so pointers to the necessary information as a resource would be invaluable..

If not I was wondering why as the undo redo logs must be accessible?

Comment: Maybe you can find a good answer here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32244/undo-region-spacemacs (of course selecting a line is just `S-v`)

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: https://evil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#elispobj-evil-want-fine-undo

Answer (score 1):

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Undo`:

> When there is an active region, any use of undo performs selective undo: it undoes the most recent change within the region, instead of the entire buffer. However, when Transient Mark mode is off (see Disabling Transient Mark Mode), <kbd>C-/</kbd> always operates on the entire buffer, ignoring the region. In this case, you can perform selective undo by supplying a prefix argument to the undo command: <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>C-/</kbd>. To undo further changes in the same region, repeat the undo command (no prefix argument is needed).

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Undo.html